# Как правильно спарсить JSON во Flutter

Tags: json, flutter, dart

У меня постоянно возникают сложности в понимании как парсить разные JSON объекты, может быть есть у кого источник для познания?
Вот конкретный JSON:

```
{
  "success": true,
  "data": {
    "country": [
      {
        "id": "67",
        "name": "Algeria",
        "is_real": "1",
        "leagues": "https://livescore-api.com/api-client/leagues/list.json?key=o77eB07ZqirxyShu&amp;secret=f8bK5NOObpYQn23Lab0Lc7LCpcaY5rsl&amp;country=67",
        "scores": "https://livescore-api.com/api-client/scores/live.json?key=o77eB07ZqirxyShu&amp;secret=f8bK5NOObpYQn23Lab0Lc7LCpcaY5rsl&amp;country=67",
        "federation": {
          "id": "3",
          "name": "CAF"
        },
        "national_team": {
          "id": "1528",
          "name": "Algeria",
          "stadium": "Stade du 5 Juillet 1962",
          "location": "Stade du 5 Juillet 1962"
        }
      }
      ]
}
}
```

- 

```
import 'dart:convert';

Country countryFromJson(String str) => Country.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String countryToJson(Country data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class Country {
  Country({
    required this.success,
    required this.data,
  });

  bool success;
  Data data;

  factory Country.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Country(
    success: json["success"],
    data: Data.fromJson(json["data"]),
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "success": success,
    "data": data.toJson(),
  };
}

class Data {
  Data({
    required this.country,
  });

  List<CountryElement> country;

  factory Data.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Data(
    country: List<CountryElement>.from(json["country"].map((x) => CountryElement.fromJson(x))),
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "country": List<dynamic>.from(country.map((x) => x.toJson())),
  };
}

class CountryElement {
  CountryElement({
    required this.id,
    required this.name,
    required this.isReal,
    required this.leagues,
    required this.scores,
    required this.federation,
    required this.nationalTeam,
  });

  String id;
  String name;
  String isReal;
  String leagues;
  String scores;
  Federation federation;
  NationalTeam nationalTeam;

  factory CountryElement.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => CountryElement(
    id: json["id"],
    name: json["name"],
    isReal: json["is_real"],
    leagues: json["leagues"],
    scores: json["scores"],
    federation: Federation.fromJson(json["federation"]),
    nationalTeam: NationalTeam.fromJson(json["national_team"]),
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "id": id,
    "name": name,
    "is_real": isReal,
    "leagues": leagues,
    "scores": scores,
    "federation": federation.toJson(),
    "national_team": nationalTeam.toJson(),
  };
}

class Federation {
  Federation({
    required this.id,
    required this.name,
  });

  String id;
  String name;

  factory Federation.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Federation(
    id: json["id"],
    name: json["name"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "id": id,
    "name": name,
  };
}

class NationalTeam {
  NationalTeam({
    required this.id,
    required this.name,
    required this.stadium,
    required this.location,
  });

  String id;
  String name;
  String stadium;
  String location;

  factory NationalTeam.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => NationalTeam(
    id: json["id"],
    name: json["name"],
    stadium: json["stadium"],
    location: json["location"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "id": id,
    "name": name,
    "stadium": stadium,
    "location": location,
  };
}
```

функция с которой всегда проблемы:

```
Future<Map<String, dynamic>> fetchCountries() async{
final url = Uri.parse('https://livescore-api.com/api-client/countries/list.json?&key=$_apiKey&secret=$_secretApiKey');
final response = await http.get(url);

if(response.statusCode == 200) {
  final parsedJson = jsonDecode(response.body) as Map<String, dynamic>;
  final countries = Country.fromJson(parsedJson);
  print(countries.runtimeType);
  return countries as Map<String, dynamic>;
}else{
  throw Exception('SHIT!!!');
}
```

}

Пытаюсь отобразить название страны, но получаю ошибку ***Unhandled Exception: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String'***

```
class CountriesWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const CountriesWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<CountriesWidget> createState() => _CountriesState();
}

class _CountriesState extends State<CountriesWidget> {
  final apiClient = ApiClient();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    apiClient.fetchCountries();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
        future: apiClient.fetchCountries(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: ListView.builder(
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, index) {
                      return GestureDetector(
                        // onTap: () => Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => LegauesWidget(countryName: snapshot.data[index].name))),
                        child: Card(
                          borderOnForeground: true,
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            side: BorderSide(color: Colors.white, width: 2),
                              borderRadius:
                                  BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0))),
                          color: Color.fromRGBO(28, 27, 31, 1),
                          child: ClipRRect(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                              topLeft: Radius.circular(10.0),
                              bottomLeft: Radius.circular(10.0),
                            ),
                            child: Row(
                              children: [
/*                                Container(
                                    height: 90,
                                    width: 120,
                                    child: FittedBox(
                                      child: SvgPicture.network(
                                          snapshot.data[index].flag),
                                    )),*/
                                SizedBox(
                                  width: 10,
                                ),
                                Flexible(
                                    child: Text("${snapshot.data[index].data.country.name}", style: countriesStyle(),))
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    }),
              );
            } else {
              return Center(
                child: Text('Нет данных'),
              );
            }
          } else if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          } else {
            return Center(
              child: Icon(
                Icons.error,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            );
          }
        });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В итоге решение проблемы было таково:

```
fetchCountries() async{
    final url = Uri.parse('https://livescore-api.com/api-client/countries/list.json?&key=$_apiKey&secret=$_secretApiKey');
    final response = await http.get(url);

    if(response.statusCode == 200) {
      final List parsedJson = jsonDecode(response.body)["data"]["country"];
      return parsedJson;
    }else{
      throw Exception('Exception');
    }
  }
```

и сам вывод названия страны:

```
Text("${snapshot.data[index]["name"]}")
```